# Angular2: How do you run 2 animations in parallel?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have a container that expands/shrinks. There is an element inside that container that should fade in when the container expands and fade out when the container shrinks.

**My Problem**

- When the container expands, the animation of both elements work.
- **When the container shrinks, only the container animation works.**
- If I remove the container expansion animation, then the fade in/out animations work as expected.

**How do I make all animations execute in parallel under both expand/shrink conditions?**

**Note** the use of *ngIf*.  This is intentional as it destroys the element at the end of the animation sequence.

Here is a plunkr of my current state:
https://embed.plnkr.co/TXYoGf9QpErWmlRvQF9Z/

The component class:

```
export class App {
  expanded = true;

  toggleExpandedState() {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

The template:

```
<div class="container" [@expansionTrigger]="expanded">
  <div class="constant-item"></div>
  <div class="fade-item" [@stateAnimation] *ngIf="expanded"></div>
</div>

<button (click)="toggleExpandedState()">Toggle Fade</button>
```

and the component animation:

```
  trigger('expansionTrigger', [
    state('1', style({
      width: '250px'
    })),
    state('0', style({
      width: '160px'
    })),
    transition('0 => 1', animate('200ms ease-in')),
    transition('1 => 0', animate('200ms ease-out'))
  ]),
  trigger('stateAnimation', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({
        opacity: 0
      }),
      animate('200ms 350ms ease-in', style({
        opacity: 1
      }))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({
        opacity: 1
      })
      animate('1s', style({
        opacity: 0
      }))
    ])
  ])
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. I think it's probably connected to this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6768

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In hopes to save others the frustration, it looks like it is a bug with Angular 4.

There are currently two open issues on Github that appear to be pretty closely related:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15798

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15753

**Update**

According to the github issue, the animation bug won't be fixed to work as it once did in Angular2.  Instead `query()` and `animateChild()` are being introduced.  The new animation features are available as of 4.2.0-rc2.

In summary:

**Component Definition**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
      <div *ngIf="show" @ngIfAnimation>
        <h3 @easeInOut>I'm inside ngIf</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
animations: [
  trigger('ngIfAnimation', [
    transition(':enter, :leave', [
      query('@*', animateChild())
    ])
  ])
  trigger('easeInOut', [
    transition('void => *', [
        style({
            opacity: 0
        }),
        animate("1s ease-in-out", style({
            opacity: 1
        }))
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
        style({
            opacity: 1
        }),
        animate("1s ease-in-out", style({
            opacity: 0
        }))
    ])
  ])
]]

})
export class App {
  name:string;
  show:boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }
}
```

There is a working example available here: https://embed.plnkr.co/RJgAunJfibBKNFt0DCZS/

Answer (score 2):

here is what you'll need to do:

plnkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/AQEVh3GGc31ivQZMp223?p=preview

remove **`*ngIf="expanded"`** use `[@stateAnimation]="expanded"`

replace your `stateAnimate` trigger with this:

```
trigger('stateAnimation', [
          state('1', style({ opacity: 0 })),
          state('0', style({opacity: 1})),
          transition('0 => 1', animate('200ms ease-in')),
          transition('1 => 0', animate('200ms ease-out'))
        ])
```

here is the full code:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, 
  Output,
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  animate,
} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="container" [@expansionTrigger]="expanded">
      <div class="constant-item"></div>
      <div class="fade-item" [@stateAnimation]="expanded"></div>
    </div>

    <button (click)="toggleExpandedState()">Toggle Fade</button>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('expansionTrigger', [
      state('1', style({ width: '250px' })),
      state('0', style({width:'160px'})),
      transition('0 => 1', animate('200ms ease-in')),
      transition('1 => 0', animate('200ms ease-out'))
    ]),
    trigger('stateAnimation', [
      state('1', style({ opacity: 0 })),
      state('0', style({opacity: 1})),
      transition('0 => 1', animate('200ms ease-in')),
      transition('1 => 0', animate('200ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class App {
  expanded = true;

  toggleExpandedState() {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }

  constructor() {
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed -- thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately that method doesn't destroy the the 'fade-item' element. This is what is creating the challenge here.

Comment: So you want the fade-item to be destroyed? You never mentioned this in your question.. please update your question with more specifics on what you're expecting.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.  Along those lines, I'm looking for an Angular2 solution.  CSS hackery to emulate the element being destroyed won't work.

Comment: @axlj I'm really curious why you want the element destroyed? Anyway, you might have some luck with the code above and Animation callbacks `.start` and `.done` described here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#animation-callbacks. That with some component change detection listener for `AfterViewChecked` to perform the animation right after the `fade-item`'s constructed or conversely right before its destroyed.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I'll take a look at the start/done events.. This question is an extremely simplified use case for what I'm trying to achieve.  I'm porting a multimedia desktop app to the web.  Destroying the elements solves a bunch of issues of which are primarily (1) minimizing resource requirements and (2) avoiding extraneous CSS to achieve the same UX.